# Building Confidence Interval for Population Proportion

Tags: probability, statistical-inference, confidence-interval

I'm having trouble understanding how the 95% confidence interval equation for population proportions gets simplified.

Here is the initial equation:
$$
Pr(\overline{X} - 2\hat{SE}(\overline{X}) ≤ p ≤ \overline{X} + 2\hat{SE}(\overline{X}))
$$

Here is what I should get after simplifying (z-score in the middle):

$$
-2 ≤ {\overline{X} - p \over \hat{SE}(\overline{X})} ≤ 2
$$

My issue is that when I subtract $\overline{X}$ in the three parts of the equation and then divide by $\hat{SE}(\overline{X})$ again in all parts of the equation, I obtain $ p - \overline{X} \over \hat{SE}(\overline{X})$, which is not the formula for the z-score.

Comment: What is your definition of the standard error estimator?

Comment: $\frac{p - \bar X}{\hat{SE}(\bar X)}= -\frac{ \bar X-p}{\hat{SE}(\bar X)}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go from $$-2 ≤ {p-\overline{X} \over \hat{SE}(\overline{X})} ≤ 2$$  by multiplying everything by $-1$ (changing the direction of inequalities) to get $$2 \ge {\overline{X} - p \over \hat{SE}(\overline{X})} \ge -2$$ and then reordering to arrive at $$-2 ≤ {\overline{X} - p \over \hat{SE}(\overline{X})} ≤ 2$$

Comment: thank you very much for the help! One comment, I imagine the sign before -2 in the second equation should be reversed as well and so ≥.

Comment: @Alex_A I have corrected the middle line changing the final $\le$ to $\ge$ so it now reads as  $2 \ge {\overline{X} - p \over \hat{SE}(\overline{X})} \ge -2$.  Thank you for pointing this out